# Setting up Sentry with PHP

Tags: php, sentry

I am trying to set up a simple test of [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) with PHP. I have tried to manually install it by Downloading and extract the [latest sentry-php archive](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/archive/master.zip) to my project folder.

I have been following the [PHP Instructions](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/php/), and have set up a simple one page php file that I thought would show that sentry is working. I included a reference to a file that doesn't exist to generate a PHP error. I know that my path to Raven/Autoloader.php is correct as i tested echoing out message from the top of that file.

I have set up a Sentry account and project and ensured that my DNS from the the sentry Client Keys page is included in the `$client = new Raven_Client` statement.

I have tried the file locally and on a hosted testing server. No errors or messages get logged in Sentry. Going to the issues page of my Sentry project it says that it is waiting for events.

Could anyone please suggest why the follow test page is not working?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Sentry Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 

// Require raven for Sentry error logging
require_once 'vendor/sentry-php-master/lib/Raven/Autoloader.php';
Raven_Autoloader::register();

// Enable Sentry automatic error and exception capturing which is recomended
$client = new Raven_Client('https://[my-DNS-key-is-here]@app.getsentry.com/82094');
$error_handler = new Raven_ErrorHandler($client);
$error_handler->registerExceptionHandler();
$error_handler->registerErrorHandler();
$error_handler->registerShutdownFunction();


// Capture a message
$event_id = $client->getIdent($client->captureMessage('Try to send a message'));

 echo '<p>Sentry test 1</p>'; 

 // Create n error by looking for a file that isn't there 
 $file=fopen("welcome.txt","r");


 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the server seeing any requests coming in (see sentry server logs)?

Comment: Under 'issues' I can only see the example errors from sentry, which are nothing to do with my one page PHP file

Comment: We got this working by installing sentry via composer instead. There was nothing wrong with the test page I had written. I think that the manual installation instructions at https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/php/ need a bit more work. For example the package that you download contains a composer.json with a require for monolog. I can’t see monolog in the download package, so presumably for a manual installation a user would need to add this themselves but this is not mentioned in the instructions.

Comment: Actually Monolog is not necessary for Raven work work. I realise now that is an optional dependency if you want to hook into monolog. So it must be something else...

Comment: Glad to hear you got it work via the composer option. We'll keep our eyes open if more people run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried runing `$client->install()` function , with it you will register all your error handlers [image: Following pic is from Sentry documentation [1]]